# How can I associate checkbox for each items of custom listview which extends BaseAdapter

Tags: android

I have Custom List to display image with it's name like below...

```
 public class LazyAdapter extends BaseAdapter {

 private Activity activity;
 private String[] data;
 private static LayoutInflater inflater=null;
 public ImageLoader imageLoader; 

 public LazyAdapter(Activity a, String[] d) {
    activity = a;
    data=d;
    inflater =  
   (LayoutInflater)activity.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    imageLoader=new ImageLoader(activity.getApplicationContext());
 }

 public int getCount() {
    return data.length;
 }

 public Object getItem(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 public long getItemId(int position) {
    return position;
 }

 public static class ViewHolder{
    public TextView text;
    public ImageView image,yesimage;

 }

 public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View vi=convertView;
    ViewHolder holder;
    if(convertView==null){
        vi = inflater.inflate(R.layout.item, null);
        holder=new ViewHolder();
        holder.text=(TextView)vi.findViewById(R.id.text);;
        holder.image=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.image);
        holder.yesimage=(ImageView)vi.findViewById(R.id.selectedyes);
        vi.setTag(holder);
    }
    else
        holder=(ViewHolder)vi.getTag();



    holder.text.setText("item "+position);
    holder.image.setTag(data[position]);
    holder.yesimage.setTag(data[position]);

    imageLoader.DisplayImage(data[position], activity, holder.image,holder.yesimage);
    return vi;
}
}
```

for this list I'm trying to set,

```
      list=(ListView)findViewById(R.id.list);
      adapter=new LazyAdapter(this, mStrings);//mstrings is array
      list.setAdapter(adapter);
      list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

where as I'm able to get all checked list items using,

```
      list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener(){

        TextView selected=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.selected);
        final ArrayList<String> years = new ArrayList<String>();

         @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                long arg3) {

            SparseBooleanArray checked = list.getCheckedItemPositions();
                    if(checked.get(arg2))
                    {
                         years.add(""+mStrings[arg2]+"\n");
                    }
                    else
                    {
                     years.remove("    "+mStrings[arg2]+"\n");
                    }

             if(years.size()!=0)
                 selected.setText(years.toString());
             else
             selected.setText("You Have Nothing in Cart");
             }});
```

but nothing indicates in list that the selected item is checked, it just considers clicked item as selected,Here I cannot use,

```
    list.setAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
android.R.layout.simple_list_item_multiple_choice, mStrings));
list.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_MULTIPLE);
```

Because my list Extends BaseAdapter,

I want to put the checkbox for every row in the list, to ensure that the item is checked once I check that list item, how can I do that...?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Take CheckBox inside the ViewHolder and implement [setOnCheckedChangeListener](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CompoundButton.html#setOnCheckedChangeListener%28android.widget.CompoundButton.OnCheckedChangeListener%29) for each check box.

for example:

```
holder.checkbox = ( CheckBox ) vi.findViewById( R.id.checkbox );
holder.checkbox.setOnCheckedChangeListener(new OnCheckedChangeListener()
{
    public void onCheckedChanged(CompoundButton buttonView, boolean isChecked)
    {
        if ( isChecked )
        {
            // perform logic
        }

    }
});
```

Comment: @user1065490 glad that my answer is helpful.

Comment: How can I make some image visible on list when i select an item of the list..                                                                    if(convertView.isSelected())                             
         holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        else
         holder.yesimage.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                                                                     I'm trying this code in the getView() method, but image is visible only once when i click any item first time.. that is  image is getting visible for all items of list even if i check single item...

Answer (score 0):

Set setOnCheckedChangeListener on checkBox and check the status of the same.
As per the code i think there will not be any majot issue you will face. Did you want to do some specific functioality on clicking on chackBox ? If yes, please share that also.

Comment: yes when i check the checkbox, the related item sould be displayed on text view called cart, it goes on updating as user goes on checking items, or if user unchecks all items or not selected any items it shows static text "You have nothing in your cart"...

Comment: You can use HashMap for storing the selected Item when user select it and remove that item when it deselct it. You can check the size of HashMap for showing on Cart.